# Как исправить проблемы со шрифтом в Visual Code

Tags: linux, шрифты, visual-studio-code

После обновления Linux возникли проблемы со шрифтом в VC, в остальных редакторах всё нормально. Кто знает как исправить проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая именно ОС?

Comment: debian - parrot os